# Equivalent norms, identity function

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

If $||*||_{1}$ and $||*||_{2}$ are norms on $X$ and $I:(X,||*||_{1}) \rightarrow  (X,||*||_{2})$ is the identity function and it is continous... are $||*||_{1}$ and $||*||_{2}$ equivalent?

It is continous, so it is bounded... in that way $||x||_{2}=||I(x)||_{2}\leq ||I||||x||_{1}\leq M||x||_{1} $.

what about a $N$ such that $N||x||_{1}\leq ||x||_{2}$ ? does it always exists? is $I^{-1}$ continous (or $I$ open)?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. For a counterexample try

$$ \mathrm{id}: (\ell^1, \|\cdot\|_1) \to (\ell^1, \|\cdot\|_\infty) $$

Comment: I need to show that this id is continous but ∥⋅∥1 and  ∥⋅∥∞ are not equivalent?

Comment: @user144507 You can show that its inverse is not bounded. Then the norms cannot be equivalent.

Comment: @matt: actually it has no inverse since the identity is not surjective here.

Comment: @Freeze_S what do you mean by saying that the identity is not surjective?

Comment: @TomekKania: Oh I misread it. Will delete my comment in a moment. Thanks for pointing on it!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your situation is that the identity function between your Banach spaces is not a bijection but that is the least you want for equivalent spaces plus the preservation of structures of course.

In general, if two norms are equivalent then the identity will be automatically a bijection and of course linear and continuous. The extra for equivalence is that both will be either complete or incomplete.

You could still ask is there another isomorphism since the first choice was a bad one...

Besides for complete spaces you can make use of the open mapping theorem that answers your question to a large extend:
Find a continuous bijection. Then the norms are equivalent.

Comment: The identity function is bijective. Pretty much by definition. The question is whether it is an isomorphism (of topological vector spaces). Generally, that doesn't follow, but if both norms make the space complete, the open mapping theorem implies that the norms are equivalent if they are comparable. For the equivalence of two norms, it is not sufficient that there exists some continuous (linear) bijection, it must be the identity.